# How do I change a column in Excel with Last Name, First Name into a column with First Name Last Name (no comma)

Tags: excel, csv

Hello how do I turn a whole column with cells like

Column 1

```
Ajrouche, Bob  
Apple, Jason A  
Richard Jr, Donald G
```

into

Column 2

```
Bob Ajrouche  
Jason A Apple  
Donald G Richard Jr
```

Thank you.

Comment: Text to columns?

Comment: A GREP search in a good text editor?

Comment: What do you mean? @findwindow

Comment: This is Excel @cybernetic.nomad

Comment: You tagged csv... which is text

Comment: Understood, the file was a csv but I was opening in excel like I said in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this in ***Excel***,

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

• Formula used in cell **C1**

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(", ",A1)-1)&LEFT(" "&A1,FIND(", ",A1)-1)
```

And If you are using **O365**, and currently in **Insiders Beta Channel**, then

• Formula used in cell **B1**

```
=TEXTAFTER(A1&" ",", ")&TEXTBEFORE(A1,", ")
```

Comment: Kindly note, even if you are applying a formula in a .csv file it wont be saved, it will disappear once it is saved as .csv, so to keep the formulas, you need to save as .xlsx or .xlsm or .xlsb, and i always prefer using workbooks in .xlsb

Answer (score 0):

Select your column and then navigate to the Data tab and click "text to columns". A wizard will open and in the second step, make sure the delimiters are set to commas.
[image]

Now You have two columns: Column A = Last name & Column B = first name. In the first cell in column C type the formula `=CONCAT(B1, A1)`. Select the cell and double click the [autofill handle](https://trumpexcel.com/how-to-use-fill-handle-in-excel/). And *voila* you have your first name last name column

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple macro. If your names are in column A, this macro will loop through them and store the converted names into column B. The loop stops when an empty cell is reached.

```
Sub FixNames()
    Range("A1").Activate
    Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
        Dim nameParts() As String
        nameParts = Split(ActiveCell.Value, ",", 2)
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = nameParts(1) + " " + nameParts(0)
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
    Loop
End Sub
```